# How can I put Jbuttons into arraylist with considering their name?

Tags: java, swing, reflection, jbutton

I have this code and I want to put all buttons in my page to in arraylist with considering their name if its name is for example btn_2 it should be the second element of the list.
It gives an error and says cannot cast field to Jbutton since my list type is Jbutton not field.his is not all my code just some of them but all code consist of ading panel then adding a button to panel also some labels.

```
getContentPane().setForeground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
getContentPane().setLocation(-405, -87);
setResizable(false);
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
getContentPane().setLayout(null);

panelPOD1 = new JPanel();
panelPOD1.setBounds(65, 13, 353, 313);
panelPOD1.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED, Color.DARK_GRAY, null, null, null));
getContentPane().add(panelPOD1);
panelPOD1.setLayout(null);

JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setBorder(new SoftBevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED, Color.DARK_GRAY, null, null, null));
panel.setBounds(10, 11, 59, 59);
panelPOD1.add(panel);
panel.setLayout(null);

btn_1 = new JButton();
btn_1.setText("");
btn_1.setEnabled(false);
btn_1.setBorder(new RoundedBorder());
btn_1.setBounds(17, 15, 26, 24);
panel.add(btn_1);

btn_3 = new JButton("");
btn_3.setEnabled(false);
btn_3.setForeground(SystemColor.textInactiveText);
btn_3.setBackground(SystemColor.activeCaption);
btn_3.setBounds(10, 15, 26, 24);
btn_3.setBorder(new RoundedBorder());
panel1.add(btn_3);
panel.setLayout(null);

btn_5 = new JButton("");
btn_5.setEnabled(false);
btn_5.setBounds(11, 15, 26, 24);
btn_5.setBorder(new RoundedBorder());
panel_1.add(btn_5);

btn_2 = new JButton("");
btn_2.setEnabled(false);
btn_2.setBounds(12, 15, 26, 24);
btn_2.setBorder(new RoundedBorder());
panel_2.add(btn_2);

btn_4 = new JButton("");
btn_4.setEnabled(false);
btn_4.setBounds(11, 15, 26, 24);
btn_4.setBorder(new RoundedBorder());
panel_3.add(btn_4);


JPanel panel_4 = new JPanel();
panel_4.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED, null, null, null, null));
panel_4.setBounds(10, 81, 59, 59);
panelPOD1.add(panel_4);
panel_4.setLayout(null);

btn_6 = new JButton("");
btn_6.setEnabled(false);
btn_6.setBounds(10, 15, 26, 24);
btn_6.setBorder(new RoundedBorder());
panel_4.add(btn_6);


Integer search_index=0;
java.lang.reflect.Field[] fields;
Integer arrayIndex=0;
ArrayList<JButton> rockets;
boolean allFound=false;
while (!allFound)
{

  for (int i =0;i<fields.length;i++) 
  {
      if(fields[i].getName().equals("btn"+arrayIndex.toString()))   
      {

          rockets.add(arrayIndex,fields[i]);
      }

      if (arrayIndex==50)
      {
          allFound = true;
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: please why by using `java.lang.reflect.Field[] fields`

Comment: Try type casting while adding to the list.

Comment: Use a Map instead? You could set the name of field directly (using setName)

Comment: Think the problem is that you are trying to add a object of type "Field" to your list with JButton.

Comment: I don't know what you are doing outside the code you posted, but why don't you put the JButton's in the ArrayList first (directly after instantiation) and then position them where you want them to be?

Comment: @Abu Dun I cant because I have 60 buttons and I use drag drop to design.

Comment: I think what everyone above is trying to say is: More code please :-)

Comment: @Rima: So where is the problem? The JButton is instanciated at some time and if you insert it into the ArrayList, at the correct position (in terms of your project) you have it always right. When you change the arragement visually you simply swap the positions in the ArrayList...

Comment: by default you don't need to put any JComponents to the array, nor from Reflection,  [search for proper answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[swing]+[jbutton]+gridlayout)

Comment: And I am not sure how ArrayList will behave if you try to insert an element at a position if the ArrayList has fewer elements at that time...

Comment: This code looks like the "hall of horrors" (sorry): 1) You use `null` layout (always use a LayoutManager) 2) You should not need to use reflection and store your buttons in an array 3) Your loop at the end will never end because `arrayIndex` is always 0. Consider telling us what you are trying to achieve because I am pretty sure this can be done a lot more easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like everyone else here, I highly doubt whether you should approach the problem this way, but if you insist, this works:

```
final int NUMBER_OF_BUTTONS = 50;
final String PREFIX = "btn_";
Field[] fields = getClass().getDeclaredFields();
JButton[] rockets = new JButton[NUMBER_OF_BUTTONS];

for (Field field : fields) {                        
    if(field.getName().startsWith(PREFIX)) {
        int index = Integer.parseInt(field.getName().substring(PREFIX.length())) - 1;
        rockets[index] = (JButton) field.get(this);
    }           
}
```

I assumed that your first button is called `btn_1`, hence the `-1` for the index.

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<JButton> rockets = new ArrayList<JButton>();

btn_1 = new JButton();
btn_1.setText("");
btn_1.setEnabled(false);
btn_1.setBorder(new RoundedBorder());
btn_1.setBounds(17, 15, 26, 24);
rockets.add(btn_1);
panel.add(btn_1);

btn_2 = new JButton("");
btn_2.setEnabled(false);
btn_2.setBounds(12, 15, 26, 24);
btn_2.setBorder(new RoundedBorder());
rockets.add(btn_2);
panel_2.add(btn_2);
```

And if you rearrange (=swap?) Buttons in your layout, you simply swap the items in `rocket`

This way you won't need to create a seperate instance of a JButton if you change the code to reuse a single variable over an over. If you need to identify an instance, you should rather subclass JButton and add an identifier than relying on a variable name that is not visible inside the ArryList.